# How to reposition labels in a stacked chart in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

For each bar, I would like to show the labels either

- all above the bar
- all below the bar
- some other alternative way than just placing the number inside the rectangle

I am currently fiddling with the properties options with no success. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: MY current stacked chart]